# Convert a string to an array in Google Dataprep

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, data-conversion, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm trying to denormalize data in Dataprep so that I can use it in BigQuery.

More specifically, I'd like to turn entries in an account_profile table linked to my account table with with foreign key 'account_id' into an array in my account table. (Account_profile stores contact methods... bad name, I know.)

In dataprep, I've

1. turned the rows in account_profile into json objects,
2. and then joined the two tables via account_id,
3. then grouped the rows by account_id and used the aggregate function LIST to convert all objects into an array of objects.

The problem is that when I try to unnest that column in BigQuery, or do any other array-like operation in BigQuery, I get an error like this: "Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays."

My data looks good.  For example, here is a row.

[{"profile_identifier":"ttcuongem+29@gmail.com","verification_code":"abc789","enabled":true,"id1":2818},{"profile_identifier":"xyz123,"enabled":false,"id1":2874}]

I can't find a way to make BigQuery see this as an array, nor can I find a way to make Dataprep create this kind of data as an array rather than a string.  The only solutions people have posted are very specific hacks that wouldn't apply to this generic case.

I feel that I'm following denormalization best practices and am surprised that this gap exists in the Google ELT toolchain.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use recently introduced [JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array) function for this as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
SELECT '''[
  {"profile_identifier":"ttcuongem+29@gmail.com","verification_code":"abc789","enabled":true,"id1":2818},
  {"profile_identifier":"xyz123","enabled":false,"id1":2874}
]''' string_col
)
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(string_col) AS arr_col
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row arr_col
1   {"profile_identifier":"ttcuongem+29@gmail.com","verification_code":"abc789","enabled":true,"id1":2818}   
    {"profile_identifier":"xyz123","enabled":false,"id1":2874}
```

Comment: Mikhail, thank you!  I ran your example and that seems to do the trick.  I was looking in the wrong places because I was focused on the array outer structure and not the json within it.  I'm about to try this technique on the real thing and will let you know how it goes.